# Javascript remove lines not containing substring from string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a script wich should remove all lines in a string not containing a certain substring. I've tried adding the lines with the string to another string, but with no luck.
Example:

Remove lines not containing *name*.

> Hello my name is Olaf.
>
> What's your name?
>
> Lazy donkey.
>
> Weird name...

Should result in:

> Hello my name is Olaf
>
> What's your name?
>
> Weird name...

Any ideas?
I've searched for a long time without an answer.

Comment: So where is the code that you are fiddling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split and filter, e.g.:

```
text.split('\n').filter(function (s) { return s.match('name') })
```